# GPAW can't find ase: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ase'

Tags: python

I am trying to install [GPAW](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/install.html), a package for [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory) simulations, but It looks like it can't find another python library called [ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/). I already installed and set the environment variables like this (as stated in the installation instructions):

export PYTHONPATH=~/.local/bin:~/bin/gpaw:~/gpaw:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=~/.local/bin:~/bin/gpaw/tools:~/gpaw/tools:$PATH

But when I try to run the test `gpaw info`, to check whether the installation is correct or not:

```
$ gpaw info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joshua/.local/bin/gpaw", line 2, in <module>
    from gpaw.cli.main import main
  File "/home/joshua/bin/gpaw/gpaw/__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
    from gpaw.calculator import GPAW
  File "/home/joshua/bin/gpaw/gpaw/calculator.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ase.units import Bohr, Ha
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ase'
```

Is there a way to check tell GPAW where ASE is? ASE already works with `$ ase test`, but not from `import ase` in python CLI.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There's a reason why people like me recommend using the packaged versions of software - it's so you can avoid a seemingly endless series of annoying problems like this.   As I suggested in your last question, install the packaged version with `apt-get install gpaw gpaw-data` and avoid duplicating the work already done by the package maintainers.  Do you want to spend your time dealing with annoyances like this, or spend your time more productively running your DFT simulations?

Comment: I already did that, but could it be in conflict with the package I instalated directly from the source on `~/bin/gpaw` ? Also I did it with `pip --upgrade --user install gpaw` and the same with `ase`. But still having the same error.

Comment: Yeah.  cleaning up the mess from a non-package install can be a real pain, because you've got unmanaged files strewn all over the OS directories.  Sometimes a local compile & install is unavoidable because there is no package, or the package maintainer has been MIA for 10 years or something...but it should be thought of as a last resort only.  and even then, use something like `stow` or `checkinstall` so you can easily uninstall or upgrade it.